# SQL - Normalizing Data returned from Select Statement / Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, neural-network, normalization

I am working on building a neural network to do some back-propagation/data analysis.

I am working on normalizing my input data for training purposes.

One of my data sets contains a type identifier, currently there are 8 types(this may change at any time).

In my select statement, I want to have a condition that if TypeId = 1, I actually want to return 00000001. If TypeId = 2, I would like to return 00000011, and repeat.  The length of the number would represent the number of Types. The number of ones represents the TypeId.

Any suggestions in how to approach this? I would prefer something a little more dynmaic than what I've provided as the number of types may change.

```
SELECT   TypeId =
      CASE TypeId
         WHEN 1 THEN 00000001
         WHEN 2 THEN 00000011
         WHEN 3 THEN 00000111
         WHEN 4 THEN 00001111
      END,
   Name
FROM dbo.Types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (TypeId INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, 'Type1'), (2, 'Type2'), (3, 'Type3'), (10, 'Type10')

SELECT REPLICATE('0', (SELECT MAX(TypeId) FROM @t) - TypeId) + REPLICATE('1', TypeId), Name
FROM @t
```

Gives:

```
0000000001  Type1
0000000011  Type2
0000000111  Type3
1111111111  Type10
```